# Bing Custom Search - sort/order by file modification date

Tags: bing-custom-search

I have been asked by a client to see if Bing Custom Search can order results containing links to PDFs by file modification date.

I know results can be ordered by the date the content was indexed (or re-indexed), but they are concerned with the actual age of PDF files as determined by the filesystem timestamp, and want to order the results by that criteria.

I could not find anything in the Azure documentation, and personally I don't believe it is possible, but I wanted to check in with SO first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this specific scenario is currently supported at the time. But if this is a feature you would like to see supported in the future, you may leave your feedback on [Uservoice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/598147-bing-custom-search-api).